# Como crear un Archivo LineString GEOJSON con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, geojson

Lo que quiero hacer es desde un PHP construir el siguiente archivo GEOJSON de lineas:

```
var linea = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
     { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0]]
          },
        "properties": {
          "name": "enlace"
                }
        }

       ]
     }
```

Estoy teniendo problemas para crear la parte de

**""coordinates": [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0]]"**

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente (vean que no estoy insertando 2 latitudes y longitudes porque no se como armarlo):

```
$geojson = array(
   'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
   'features'  => array()
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature', 
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'LineString',
            'coordinates' => array($row['lon'], $row['lat'])
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'name' => $row['equipo'],
            )
        );
    array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
}

}

$variable="var geonokia= " .json_encode($geojson); 
file_put_contents('D:\equipo.js',$variable);
```

tengo 4 columnas de la base de datos que son $latA,$lonA,$latB,$lonB.

Intente agregarlo asi pero hay error de sintaxis:

**'coordinates' =>  [[$row['latA'],$row['lonA']],[$row['latB'],$row['lonB']]**

***Saben donde esta el error y como puedo corregirlo?***

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

Si vas a trabajar con latitud y longitud te recomiendo que utilices el tipo de datos [POINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-class-point.html) en tu base de datos.

Así te será mucho más fácil construir tu  GeoJSON. También sería de ayuda que muestres el resultado de la query o la consulta para poder ayudarte mejor.

¡Un saludo!